# How to manually boot Arch Linux from preboot emergency shell?

Tags: shell, arch-linux, boot, uefi, mkinitcpio

I broke an Arch Linux installation. Let's say I made a typo in the PARTUUID string. The result is that the boot process can't mount the root file system and stops at the mkinitcpio preboot stage with the error message:

> Your are now being dropped into an emergency shell.

#### Regression #1: mount + exec

[blog.entwicklerseite.de has an example how to manually boot from `rootfs`](https://blog.entwicklerseite.de/configuration/operating_systems/linux/arch/), like:

```
# mount /dev/sda2 /new_root/
# exec /usr/bin/switch_root /new_root /sbin/init
```

That brings these messages to the console output:

```
Trying to run as user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd. 
Trying to continue (this will most likely fail) ... 
...
ERROR: Failed to mount the real root device. 
Bailing out, you are now on your own. Good luck.
...
```

And a kernel panic.

#### Regression #2: set root + mount + exec

```
# root=/dev/sda2
# mount /dev/sda2 /new_root/
# exec /usr/bin/switch_root /new_root /sbin/init
```

No change in the output with that version.

With which commands can I continue booting (manually) from the Arch Linux emergency shell?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Later I found a posting on the Arch Linux forum, in thread "[Arch fails to mount my root partition](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1596581#p1596581)".

The solution to **boot Arch Linux from the emergency shell** is even less typing:

```
# mount /dev/sda2 new_root
# exit
```

Comment: You've have saved my life.

Comment: You've saved my life too but I realize that the solution was almost given in the error messages.